# Cannot create row of size greater than 8060 (a weird case for this error message)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting an error "Cannot create a row of size 8766 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060."

This happens in a query that has a LOT of columns, about 300, most of type "int" or "float". This query calculates an HRM report that has 31 columns (one for each day). Posting this query here would probably take too much space, but if you insist, I could. I am sure that 300 columns of float (4 or even 8 bytes) and some varchars should never exceed 8060 bytes. Still, the error happens. Problem is, it happens in a wierd way.

In the first level of this query, it looks something like this:

```
select  
Title,
K0Present, K1Present, K2Present,
HT,K0_T,
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y01,
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y02
...
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y31
from
(_inner_query_)
order by Title
```

Now, inner query has about 300 columns. Here in the outer query we have 37 columns. It causes the error message.

However, if I change it to this:

```
select  
*,
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y01,
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y02
...
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y31
from
(_inner_query_)
order by Title
```

the error message is gone! Even though now there are ~300 more coulmns in the output window!

How do I work on solving this problem? I haven't got a clue. Maybe there's something wierd going with the query optimizer? Maybe it somehow mis-optimizes my query?

Comment: I'm assuming this is just a select and not an insert, in which case this could be caused by a sort in the plan, and the change to the query changes the plan in such a way that it is no longer needed.  Can you post the exact error?

Comment: The exact error is, as I said, "Cannot create a row of size 8766 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060"

Answer (score 1):

If your physical data size is less than `8060` and still you are getting this error, try the following command.

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE
```

for example,

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE (Databasename,'tablename', 0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could investigate which column is a problem..try select column by column

```
select  
Title,
*
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y01,
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y02
...
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y31
from
(_inner_query_)
order by Title
```

then

```
select 
K0Present,
*
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y01,
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y02
...
case when bla bla then bla bla when bla bla then bla bla end as Y31
from
(_inner_query_)
order by Title
```

and so on..

Maybe is a problem and with ORDER BY..try execute query whitout it.This could help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.120).aspx